# CSS Opacity Box

Tags: css

Alright So here is my CSS style sheet.

```
 #mainheader,#content{
    opacity:0.35;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-top-style:ridge;
    border-left-style:ridge;
    border-right-style:ridge;
    border-bottom-style:ridge;
}
```

And as you can see it's a box that's see through, but has a small black background making text look fuzzy. Example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18dOZ.png

When I take away that background color I get more clear text like this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixLva.png

Alright So what i'm trying to say it what can I write to have that text above that box being very clear text and not with it's dark opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `rgba` instead of `opacity` like so:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
```

*Note: this is CSS3 and will only work in IE9 and up, so for other versions you should provide a **fallback** like so:*

```
background-color: #000;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use CSS3, try:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
```

instead of `opacity`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vsZtM/

References from W3.org about RGBA:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#rgba-color
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/RGBA

Answer (score 3):

Instead of opacity, change background of containers with an alpha channel:

```
#mainheader,#content { 
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
```

Where last param is the opacity.

Answer (score 3):

Opacity changes the opacity for the entire *element*, while `background:rgba(0,0,0,.35)` will change only the background color.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `background-color` as an `rgba` value, and leave off the `opacity` in your CSS statement. For example:

```
#mainheader,#content{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    border-top-style:ridge;
    border-left-style:ridge;
    border-right-style:ridge;
    border-bottom-style:ridge;
}
```

This will let your text stay fully opaque, while your background is semi-transparent. As a note, however, this will not work in Internet Explorer 8 and below -- it will be a solid background.